# Where is body field label stored in database

Tags: 7, caching, entities, database

Due some caching problems I can't immediately change field label via /admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields. So I thought that I will able to do it from mysql but I can't find it. Any help?

Please note, that I have developement state here /admin/config/development/performance - no caching at all, no compressing

Comment: Could you specify what are the caching problems?

Comment: I don't know, what causes this behavior. This is my assumption.

Answer (score 6):

The field label, together with all other settings are stored as a serialized array in the field_config_instance table.

Manually changing a serialized array is usually a bad idea, it can destroy the data in there if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is no such thing like label in field_config_instance. And YES, changing db data is dangerous, but I have no other choice. I'm running D7.14

Comment: Well, there is for me. As I said, it's part of the serialized data column, not a separate column. No idea why you wouldn't have another choice. I've warned you ;)